# Apache PHP Downloading a file on page load

Tags: php, dns

Every time I load the following site http://example.tk or ml or ga or gq,
Nothing loads, It downloads a file relative to the url, http://example.tk/domain would download a file called "domain". it may be something to do with DNS though, I have added DNS into the equation because when i use direct hosts to the IP it works fine.

I am only asking as a last resort. tried many things and this is the only thing not working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=301,L]
AccessFileName     .htaccess
UseCanonicalName Off
Alias /error_pages_domain /var/www/errors
Alias /error_pages_domain/js /var/www/errors/js
Alias /error_pages_domain/css /var/www/errors/css
 ErrorDocument 400 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=400
 ErrorDocument 401 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=401
 ErrorDocument 402 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=402
 ErrorDocument 403 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=403
 ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=404
 ErrorDocument 405 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=405
 ErrorDocument 406 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=406
 ErrorDocument 407 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=407
 ErrorDocument 408 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=408
 ErrorDocument 409 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=409
 ErrorDocument 410 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=410
 ErrorDocument 411 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=411
 ErrorDocument 412 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=412
 ErrorDocument 413 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=413
 ErrorDocument 414 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=414
 ErrorDocument 415 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=415
 ErrorDocument 500 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=500
 ErrorDocument 501 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=501
 ErrorDocument 502 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=502
 ErrorDocument 503 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=503
 ErrorDocument 504 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=504
 ErrorDocument 505 /error_pages_domain/error.php?type=505   
<Directory "/var/www/domains">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/errors>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.shtml
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from all
 </Directory>
 Servername example.tk
 ServerAlias www.example.* example.*
 ServerAlias *.examdns.tk
 ServerAlias examdns.tk
 Documentroot /var/www/domains/example.tk/public_html
 </VirtualHost>
```

DNS Records:

```
Type: A name: example.com  Domain_ID:0 Content: {ipofhost1} ttl: 120
Type: A name: example.com  Domain_ID:0 Content: {ipofhost2} ttl: 120
Type: A name: example.com  Domain_ID:0 Content: {ipofhost3} ttl: 120
Type: CNAME name: example.com  Domain_ID:0 Content: {hostnameofhost4} ttl: 120
Type: SOA name: example.com  Domain_ID:0 Content: ns01.examdns.tk ns02.examdns.tk ttl: 86400
```

Comment: So what headers do the request responses show in your browsers debug console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was what I suspected.
tampered with DNS records and it turns out one of the hostnames for the 4th server was using a no-ip hostname that hadn't been updated in a long time.